# How can I shorten my if statements

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, arraylist

Good afternoon folks.
I am trying to code a little program which mimics the code wheel which was included in the computer game The Secret Of Monkey Island. It consists of two cardboard wheels with pirate faces on it. Combining the upper half of the face with another lower half shows different year dates in windows cut out of the second disk. You can see it here: [Dial-A-Pirate](http://www.oldgames.sk/docs/Dial-A-Pirate/)

So far the task seems pretty straight forward for me. I have an array for my years and two array lists for the identifier of the images file names:

```
private int [][] years = {  {1710,  1651,   1679,   1719,   1694,   1632,   1668,   1703,   1726,   1564,   1615,   1599,   1669,   1660,   1687},
                            {1658,  1702,   1725,   1630,   1709,   1594,   1614,   1563,   1649,   1693,   1577,   1678,   1686,   1597,   1718},
                            {1724,  1667,   1691,   1685,   1613,   1580,   1723,   1717,   1684,   1628,   1643,   1559,   1573,   1708,   1701},
                            {1672,  1562,   1721,   1666,   1673,   1670,   1692,   1656,   1567,   1674,   1662,   1655,   1646,   1671,   1611},
                            {1627,  1707,   1688,   1699,   1568,   1705,   1579,   1585,   1665,   1706,   1506,   1722,   1716,   1584,   1551},
                            {1566,  1592,   1654,   1635,   1639,   1695,   1704,   1711,   1609,   1681,   1712,   1542,   1565,   1720,   1664},
                            {1690,  1682,   1601,   1619,   1680,   1621,   1652,   1689,   1713,   1697,   1696,   1624,   1604,   1653,   1641}};

ArrayList<Integer> disk1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> disk2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();


public void createDisks() {
    int i;
    for(i=1; i <=29; i = i +2 ){
        disk1.add(i);
    }
    for(i=2; i <=30; i = i +2 ){
        disk2.add(i);
    }
}
```

I use collections.rotate to rotate my lists by one and am only looking at [0] [0].
Since there are only 15 really different combination of the wheel I created an int pirateID to set the labels to the corresponding years in the arrays.
And this lead me to my question. The only possible way of doing that I came up with is a huge if-statement:

```
    private int getPirateID() {

    String temp = Integer.toString(disk1.get(0)) + Integer.toString(disk2.get(0));
    pirateID = Integer.parseInt(temp);

    if (pirateID == 12 || pirateID == 34 || pirateID == 56 || pirateID == 78 || pirateID == 910 || pirateID == 1112 || pirateID == 1314 || pirateID == 1516 || pirateID == 1718 || pirateID == 1920 || pirateID == 2122 || pirateID == 2324 || pirateID == 2526 || pirateID == 2728 || pirateID == 2930) {

        pirateID = 0;
    }

    if (pirateID == 130 || pirateID == 32 || pirateID == 54 || pirateID == 76 || pirateID == 98 || pirateID == 1110 || pirateID == 1312 || pirateID == 1514 || pirateID == 1716 || pirateID == 1918 || pirateID == 2120 || pirateID == 2322 || pirateID == 2524 || pirateID == 2726 || pirateID == 2928) {

        pirateID = 1;
    }

    if (pirateID == 128 || pirateID == 330 || pirateID == 52 || pirateID == 74 || pirateID == 96 || pirateID == 118 || pirateID == 1310 || pirateID == 1512 || pirateID == 1714 || pirateID == 1916 || pirateID == 2118 || pirateID == 2320 || pirateID == 2522 || pirateID == 2724 || pirateID == 2926) {
        pirateID = 2;
    }

    if (pirateID == 126 || pirateID == 328 || pirateID == 530 || pirateID == 72 || pirateID == 94 || pirateID == 116 || pirateID == 138 || pirateID == 1510 || pirateID == 1712 || pirateID == 1914 || pirateID == 2116 || pirateID == 2318 || pirateID == 2520 || pirateID == 2722 || pirateID == 2924) {
        pirateID = 3;
    }

    if (pirateID == 124 || pirateID == 326 || pirateID == 528 || pirateID == 730 || pirateID == 92 || pirateID == 114 || pirateID == 136 || pirateID == 158 || pirateID == 1710 || pirateID == 1912 || pirateID == 2114 || pirateID == 2316 || pirateID == 2518 || pirateID == 2720 || pirateID == 2922) {
        pirateID = 4;
    }

    if (pirateID == 122 || pirateID == 324 || pirateID == 526 || pirateID == 728 || pirateID == 930 || pirateID == 112 || pirateID == 134 || pirateID == 156 || pirateID == 178 || pirateID == 1910 || pirateID == 2112 || pirateID == 2314 || pirateID == 2516 || pirateID == 2718 || pirateID == 2920) {
        pirateID = 5;
    }

    if (pirateID == 120 || pirateID == 322 || pirateID == 524 || pirateID == 726 || pirateID == 928 || pirateID == 1130 || pirateID == 132 || pirateID == 154 || pirateID == 176 || pirateID == 198 || pirateID == 2110 || pirateID == 2312 || pirateID == 2514 || pirateID == 2716 || pirateID == 2918) {
        pirateID = 6;
    }

    if (pirateID == 118 || pirateID == 320 || pirateID == 522 || pirateID == 724 || pirateID == 926 || pirateID == 1128 || pirateID == 1330 || pirateID == 152 || pirateID == 174 || pirateID == 196 || pirateID == 218 || pirateID == 2310 || pirateID == 2512 || pirateID == 2714 || pirateID == 2916) {
        pirateID = 7;
    }

    if (pirateID == 116 || pirateID == 318 || pirateID == 520 || pirateID == 722 || pirateID == 924 || pirateID == 1126 || pirateID == 1328 || pirateID == 1530 || pirateID == 172 || pirateID == 194 || pirateID == 216 || pirateID == 238 || pirateID == 2510 || pirateID == 2712 || pirateID == 2914) {
        pirateID = 8;
    }

    if (pirateID == 114 || pirateID == 316 || pirateID == 518 || pirateID == 720 || pirateID == 922 || pirateID == 1124 || pirateID == 1326 || pirateID == 1528 || pirateID == 1730 || pirateID == 192 || pirateID == 214 || pirateID == 236 || pirateID == 258 || pirateID == 2710 || pirateID == 2912) {
        pirateID = 9;
    }

    if (pirateID == 112 || pirateID == 314 || pirateID == 516 || pirateID == 718 || pirateID == 920 || pirateID == 1122 || pirateID == 1324 || pirateID == 1526 || pirateID == 1728 || pirateID == 1930 || pirateID == 212 || pirateID == 234 || pirateID == 256 || pirateID == 278 || pirateID == 2910) {
        pirateID = 10;
    }

    if (pirateID == 110 || pirateID == 312 || pirateID == 514 || pirateID == 716 || pirateID == 918 || pirateID == 1120 || pirateID == 1322 || pirateID == 1524 || pirateID == 1726 || pirateID == 1928 || pirateID == 2130 || pirateID == 232 || pirateID == 254 || pirateID == 276 || pirateID == 298) {
        pirateID = 11;
    }
    if (pirateID == 18 || pirateID == 310 || pirateID == 512 || pirateID == 714 || pirateID == 916 || pirateID == 1118 || pirateID == 1320 || pirateID == 1522 || pirateID == 1724 || pirateID == 1926 || pirateID == 2128 || pirateID == 2330 || pirateID == 252 || pirateID == 274 || pirateID == 296) {
        pirateID = 12;
    }
    if (pirateID == 16 || pirateID == 38 || pirateID == 510 || pirateID == 712 || pirateID == 914 || pirateID == 1116 || pirateID == 1318 || pirateID == 1520 || pirateID == 1722 || pirateID == 1924 || pirateID == 2126 || pirateID == 2328 || pirateID == 2530 || pirateID == 272 || pirateID == 294) {
        pirateID = 13;
    }
    if (pirateID == 14 || pirateID == 36 || pirateID == 58 || pirateID == 710 || pirateID == 912 || pirateID == 1114 || pirateID == 1316 || pirateID == 1518 || pirateID == 1720 || pirateID == 1922 || pirateID == 2124 || pirateID == 2326 || pirateID == 2528 || pirateID == 2730 || pirateID == 292) {
        pirateID = 14;
    }


    return pirateID;
}
```

But that really can't be it? There has to be a much shorter way of doing this, right?

Comment: I'm still new, but can someone tell me if this post would be a better fit on code review?

Comment: [Codereview SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better place for this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is better suited for Code Review SE!

Comment: Use a `switch` statement. Or create a `Map<Integer, Integer>` and do a map lookup.

Comment: Just have the year matrix and keep an int pointing at the current offset. You don't need the other stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `switch` statement:

```
switch(pirateID) {
      case 12:
      case 34:
      case 56:
          pirateID = 1;
          break;
      case 130:
      case 32:
      case 54:
          pirateID = 0;
          break;
}
```

... and so on.

It's a bad habit to use the same variable for input and output in this kind of situation -- changing values get confusing. Why not:

```
final int userInput = Integer.parseInt(temp);
final int pirateId;
switch(userInput) {
    case 12:
         pirateId = 1;
    ...
    default:
         pirateId = 10;
}
```

Another option is to fill a `Map`:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> idMap = new HashMap<>();
idMap.put(12,1);
idMap.put(130,0);
... etc.

pirateId = idMap.get(userInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for each `if` condition and use `al.contains(pirateID)` for each one. It's an awful lot of `if`s still, but the overall code is shorter.

Something like:

```
int [] array1 = {12, 34, 56, 78, 910, 1112, 1314, 1516, 1718, 1920, 2122, 2324, 2526, 2728, 2930};
int [] array2 = {130, 32, 54, 76, 98, 1110, 1312, 1514, 1716, 1918, 2120, 2322, 2524, 2926, 2928};

if (Arrays.asList(array2).contains(pirateID)) {
    pirateID = 0;
} else if (Arrays.asList(array2).contains(pirateID)) {

    pirateID = 1;
}
// etc...
```

**Edit**: As suggested by @slim, added an else if to chain them together.

Comment: In terms of performance that's a horrible solution.

Comment: @Lothar if you added an `else` it would be equivalent performance-wise to the version in the question.

Comment: @slim Yes, but it's still horrible ;-) The solution you described in your answer is much better, since it's O(1) (except the Map variant) instead of O(n)